# Use SQL To Test If "Binary String" A is a Subset of "Binary String" B

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The enterprise system we have to use stores a pattern of weeks something occurs as a kind of fake "binary string" (it is a string always 52 characters long and the values are either 0 or 1, but it can have leading zeroes on it, etc.)

If something occurs in a given week, that position in the string is set to 1, otherwise it is set to 0.

There are occasions when Type Of Thing That Can Happen "A" has to occur within a set of weeks that is a subset of Type Of Thing That Can Happen "B". So, for example, "B" might be "Weeks This Person Is In The Country" and "A" might be "Weeks This Person Is At The Downtown Office".

Is there any way, using SQL, to select all occurrences where (given other parameters in the WHERE clause narrowing down records correctly), WeekPatternA is not a subset (proper or improper) or WeekPatternB?

If I were able to use C or something I know I could just loop through and find the first instance of a '1' in string A where there is not also a '1' in string B, but I don't think I can do that using SQL?

Here is some Sample Data:

**This would pass the test**

*Parent Event Week Pattern*

0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000

*Child Event Week Pattern* (must be contained within weeks of parent)

0101010101011000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**This would not pass the test**

*Parent Event Week Pattern*

0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000

*Child Event Week Pattern* (must be contained within weeks of parent)

0101010101011011100000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Try showing us some sample data to work with

Comment: @DaleK I have edited it for you, now. I hope it makes sense. I do not know if the problem is soluble in SQL

Comment: what is the version of `sql-server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I were able to use C or something I know I could just loop through and find the first instance of a '1' in string A where there is not also a '1' in string B

```
declare @t table(parent varchar(52), child varchar(52));

insert into @t
values
('0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0101010101011000000000000000000000000000000000000000'),--p
('0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0101010101011011100000000000000000000000000000000000'), --f
('10001', '10101'),--f
('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111', '0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010');--p

select *
from @t as t
where not exists
(
    select *
    from
    (
    --52 values, 1..52
    select top(52) row_number() over(order by @@spid) as rn
    from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as a(n)
    cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as b(n)
    ) as v
    --assuming parent&child have the same lengths
    where substring(t.parent,v.rn,1) = '0' and substring(t.child,v.rn,1) = '1'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, we need to just identify if the child pattern falls within the limits of the parent pattern and it is not necessary that the pattern should match.

The below two conditions will give you the answer. Sample working Code [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ef44bf47ceb9e6025a44c5f72dc0719)

1. `lastIndex` of `1` from `parent` and `child` pattern and see if the lastIndex of child is `<=` of the lastIndex of parent
2. Number of `1`'s in Parent should be `>=` of the child

To get the lastIndex

```
DECLARE @parentPattern NVARCHAR(100) = '0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
DECLARE @childPattern NVARCHAR(100) = '0111110111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000'

SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX('1', REVERSE(@parentPattern)) <= CHARINDEX('1', REVERSE(@childPattern))
    AND LEN(REPLACE(@parentPattern, '0', '')) >= LEN(REPLACE(@childPattern, '0', '')), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS Result
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hello - Your understanding is almost perfect, but there is an exception I think will not be caught. If the missing weeks falls in the middle of the parent week pattern (not at the end) it will not be picked up. A short example is: Parent '10001' and Child '10101' should be picked up, because the third week is OFF in Parent, but ON in Child

Comment: What you mean by picked up (the result should be true?), If that is the case Parent `10001` and Child `10101` will get picked up right, LastIndex in Parent is `0` and in Child is `0` and we are doing `<=`

Comment: Oh sorry I mean that the situation I gave violates the rules for a "good record". Would this not give LastIndex of both Parent and Child as being '5' because the final character '1' in both strings is at CharIndex of '5'? But in the middle of the string, there is a condition violation (because the value at CharIndex '3' in Child is 1, but in Parent it is 0, and the '1' values have to be the subset)

Comment: @TigerBailey, Updated the answer. Please check